# Powerpoint cannot be opened by specifying the version c#

Tags: c#, windows, ms-office, powerpoint, office-automation

In my application there is an option to start MS power point by specifying the version. I have been using the following code to start ppt

```
openPPT(int Version, string strFileName)
{
    if(Version == 2010)
        objectName = "Powerpoint.Application.14";
    if(Version == 2013)
        objectName = "Powerpoint.Application.15";
    if(Version == 2016)
        objectName = "Powerpoint.Application.16";

        oPPT = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application(objectName);
        oPPT.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
        objPresSet = oPPT.Presentations;
        objPres = objPresSet.Open(strFileName, MsoTriState.msoFalse,MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue);
}
```

When it is executed on a pc with all three versions installed, it opens in powerpoint 2016 no matter what the value is in `Version`.

Please help and can anyone point out why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PowerPoint.Application\CurVer

I'm not positive, but I suspect it governs which version of the application opens when you create a PPT object.